# Scrollto element defined as $this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid I'm working on that's interface is pretty dynamic, to say the least.

What I'm trying to do is focus on the $this element where ever it is, whether it's moved to the top of the page on click or back into it's original spot in the grid.

What happens is when an element is clicked.. it's sent to the top of the page, then when it's clicked again it goes back to its original place in the grid.

All the elements have the same class name and on click the element that's clicked triggers the class name selected. So I can't really target it with scrolltop.

So what I've tried is

```
$container.find('a').click( function() {
var $this = $(this),
    $photo = $this.parents('.photo');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $this.offset().top});
```

But it's not working properly. It doesn't scroll to $this, it scrolls to some random spot on the page.

## **Is there a better approach?**

Comment: Debug `$this.offset().top` and see if the value looks realistic. If it is, he issue is with `scrollTo()`. If not, you need to figure out why.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your code?

Comment: this event is triggered before or after the element is moved on top of the page? or moved again in it's original position? it only moved in the DOM or it's regenerated from scatch by some framework? the move event and the scrollTo event can be merged?

Comment: You should include the HTML on which this code acts. In other words, a [mcve]. Otherwise, we're guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't working because the page was being scrolled before isotope finished re-arranging the layout. What I did was I listened for the isotope event `arrangeComplete` and then I called `scrollTop` instead of `scrollTo`.

```
$container.one('arrangeComplete',function(){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $this.offset().top});
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g0z345v7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$("a[href^='#']").on("click", function(e) {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="top">Top</h1>
<a href="#1">Scroll to id 1</a>
<a href="#2">Scroll to id 2</a>
<a href="#3">Scroll to id 3</a>
<a href="#4">Scroll to id 4</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="1">ID 1</div>
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="2">ID 2</div>
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="3">ID 3</div>
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="4">ID 4</div>
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it appears as though you are just lacking a call to `preventDefault()`. Without that call, the browser attempts to navigate to the URL defined in the `href` of the `a`.

In the following snippet, when I click on the "a" next to, say, "11." it scrolls that 11 to the top of the window. Without the call to `e.preventDefault()` it would scroll to the Hello, wrapped in a `h1` with an id of `top`.

```js
$(function() {
  var $container = $('.container');
  $container.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $this.offset().top
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="top">Hello</h1>
<ol class="container">
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#top">a</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: to be exactly specific. here's a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/g0z345v7/1/